# How to delete 1 struct from a list of structs if matching the variable?

Tags: c++, list, struct

So I am attempting to delete all of the variables of a struct from a list, my struct is as so

```
struct LoginDetails
{
public:
    string userName;
    string userFirstName;
    string userLastName;
    string password;
    string tutor;
    int userAccess;
};
```

How do I add to the following code to then remove all of what is in the struct.

```
cout << "Please enter a username to upgrade the account.\n";
cin >> username;
for (list<LoginDetails>::iterator itri = loginDetails->begin(); itri != loginDetails->end(); itri++)
{
    if (itri->userName == username)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by delete. Do you mean *erase*?

Comment: Please clarify! What do you mean with "_remove all of what is in the struct."_ Resetting to default constructor values?

Comment: I want to be able to remove individual structs from the list.

Comment: @user2249719 [`std::list::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) then.

Comment: Consider http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove_if/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to *erase* items from list, you can do like following :

```
 list<LoginDetails>::iterator itri = loginDetails->begin(); 
 while (  itri != loginDetails->end() )
 {
    if (itri->userName == username)
    {
        loginDetails->erase(itri++);
    }

    else
    {
        ++itri;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
   for (list<LoginDetails>::iterator itri = loginDetails->begin(); itri != loginDetails->end(); )
   {
      if (itri->userName == username)
      {
         itri =  loginDetails->erase(itri);               
      }
      else
         itri++;
   }
```

But remember for list you can erase an element without affecting the validity to any iterators to other elements. Other containers like vector or deque are not so kind. For those containers only elements before the erased iterator remain untouched. This difference is simply because lists store elements in individually allocated nodes. It's easy to take one link out. vectors are contiguous, taking one element out moves all elements after it back one position.